# pretrained roberta relation extraction attribute error

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, roberta

I am trying to get the following pretrained huggingface model to work: https://huggingface.co/mmoradi/Robust-Biomed-RoBERTa-RelationClassification

I use the following code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
  
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("mmoradi/Robust-Biomed-RoBERTa-RelationClassification")

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("mmoradi/Robust-Biomed-RoBERTa-RelationClassification")

inputs = tokenizer("""The colorectal cancer was caused by mutations in angina""")
outputs = model(**inputs)
```

For some reason, I get the following error when trying to produce outputs, so in the last line of my code:

> --> 796             input_shape = input_ids.size()
> 797         elif inputs_embeds is not None:
> 798             input_shape = inputs_embeds.size()[:-1]
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'

The inputs look like this:

```
{'input_ids': [0, 133, 11311, 1688, 3894, 337, 1668, 21, 1726, 30, 28513, 11, 1480, 347, 2], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

I have no idea how to go about debugging this, so any help or hints are welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the type of tensor that you want in return for `tokenizer`. If you don't, it will return a dictionary with two lists (`input_ids` and `attention_mask`):

```
inputs = tokenizer("""The colorectal cancer was caused by mutations in angina""", return_tensors="pt")
```